# How do I create scale scores from item-level multiply imputed data in R?

Tags: r, data-imputation, mice

I have been able to create 5 multiply imputed datasets using the mice package on R. I computed at the item level so now I have to calculate scale scores for each of the 5 imputed datasets before running my analyses.

My attempt has been to pull out each of the 5 datasets and then using the scoreItems function on each imputed dataset for each scale I need to calculate. If this is the correct next step, how do I run my analyses (e.g., hierarchical cluster analysis) so that it pools the scale scores from all 5 imputed datasets? The answers I've searched online say to use the pool function, but that seems to address multiply imputed datasets at the scale level, not item level.

Thanks, hope this was clear.